# Fluent-ffmpeg won't process/do anything with videos - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have this code:

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

app.put("/upload-content", async (req, res) => {
  // 1. Get video and save locally to the server
  const video = req.files.video;
  const localTempPath = "./tmp/" + video.name;
  video.mv(localTempPath, function (error) {
      if (error) return res.send(error);
  });
  // 2. Convert video and apply settings
  processVideo(localTempPath).catch((err) => {
    return res.send(err);
  });
  return res.send("done");
});

function processVideo(localTempPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg(localTempPath)
    .withVideoCodec("libx264")
    .withSize("630x320")
    .withOutputFormat("avi")
    .on("error", (error) => reject("Failed to process video: " + error))
    .on("progress", (progress) => console.log(progress))
    .on("end", resolve("Successfully processed video"))
    .saveToFile(localTempPath);
  });
}
```

Nothing works, I have tried just taking away audio, tried changing the video codec, tried outputting instead of saving, tried it outside a promise. I've also tried different Paths etc.
When the request is sent, the `res.send('done')` practically gets sent straight away so it clearing isn't running either, there's no errors and I know the function is getting run as I have put debug statements inside it...still nothing.

Comment: @kg99 Sorry, forgot to mention, I have done that way too, still nothing. I just put 'changed the promise' in my question. I can add that code too if you'd like>

Comment: Wait for the promise.

Comment: something like  try {
    await processVideo(localTempPath);
    return res.send("done");
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }

Comment: @kg99 Still does not work, I'm afraid.

Comment: what happens? Do you get the outputs

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues. You are not waiting for the mv callback. Either make it a promise as well or run the code after its callback. Try this.

```
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

app.put("/upload-content", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        // 1. Get video and save locally to the server
        const video = req.files.video;
        const localTempPath = "./tmp/" + video.name;
        video.mv(localTempPath, async function(error) {
            if (error) return res.send(error);
            const resp = await processVideo(localTempPath);
            return res.send("done");
        });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.send(error);
    }
});

function processVideo(localTempPath) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg()
        .input(localTempPath)
        .withVideoCodec("libx264")
        .withSize("630x320")
        .withOutputFormat("avi")
        .on("error", (error) => reject("Failed to process video: " + error))
        .output(newpath)
        .on("progress", (progress) => console.log(progress))
        .on('end', function() {
            console.log('Finished processing');
        })
        .run();
});;
}
```

Either make this function a promise or execute after its called back.

```
video.mv(localTempPath, function (error) {
      if (error) return res.send(error);
 // save file if nothing went wrong. Also wait for processVideo to complete.
  });
```

Comment: I tried both your verison, and the promise verison I made and it still does not work. No errors or outputs. I will upadte my answer with the two new updates in a second

Comment: What happens. Do you get an error? Are there any logs from the processVideo function. You need to be specific.

Comment: I stated that theres not erros or logs on any functions in the first comment...I've added debug logs and they are running, so the function is running

Comment: That means you have an issue with fluent-ffmpeg. What type of video are you using?

Comment: How would you debug ffmpeg when its not stating theres an error?

Comment: This should work.  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg()
            .input(localTempPath)
            .withVideoCodec("libx264")
            .withSize("630x320")
            .withOutputFormat("avi")
            .on("error", (error) => reject("Failed to process video: " + error))
            .output(newpath)
            .on('end', function() {
                console.log('Finished processing');
            })
            .run();
    });

Comment: Could you stick that in your answer please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224986/discussion-between-kg99-and-nathan).